# Typing speed stuck at 45 wpm after 5 months of practice

Tags: typing

I have been practicing touchtyping for 5 months now , I started with typingclub, then I moved to key.br, and now I am using 10fastfinger.com.  I also played typingrush.com .

I am using a customized french keyboard AWERTY where I interchanged Z and the W key. I suspect that is part of the reason for my lack of progress .

The issue I have is that my speed has only increased steadily from 37.3 wpm to 47 wpm in 5 month of practice, 20 minutes per day with a total of 24 hours of practice on key.br.

I use letter and characters to practice on the site .

My question, which technique should I use to increase my speed to at least 60 wpm in one month and 100 wpm by Feb next year?

I have been watching videos on youtube, I applied their advice but in vain.

If someone want have a look to my keybr profile, [here](https://www.keybr.com/profile/e4njbi5) it is

Answer (score 2):

Don't know your training approach.

I went to 45wpm in two weeks.  I got to 110wpm later however most of that was from using my typing and practicing.

I recommend the Star Touch Typewriting course if  you can still find it.  That would be for a standard keyboard though.

I will say absolutely that the textbook approach is slow and ineffective when after a year students  might hit 45wpm.

So part of speed is **proper** training,  part is practice,  and part is your mental ability and physical ability working together with your fingers.

Most pianists do not start out playing Chopin but rather with the basics.  It takes time and practice, proper practice, then repeat with more advanced proper practice to become proficient.

One tip that worked for me is to use practice material with all the common pairs, triplets, and high appearance 4 or 5 letter combinations.  Practicing those will greatly improve your overall speed even if you are a bit slower on some infrequent letter combinations.  You can find lists with example for 3 letter combinations:  ion ing est ...  if your course does not them.

That approach worked well for me with TT and was verified when I passed my morse code test given by the FCC.  The right sort of practice is a big help.

Also, I mentally TTed license plates while I was driving.  The brain connection to fingers was reinforced even though I was not physically moving them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I am also suspecting my training approach to be the issue,

Comment: As you talk about letter combinaison , can you give  a link to materials and website which train on those combos?